# How to get the Closest point in Polyline from our current location

Tags: android, location

I have a list of Lats and Longs together form a Polyline and a current location. Now how can I find from a know position to the closest point(LatLng) in the polyline?

Comment: see [this](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html)

Comment: @pskink I have gone through this link before but it seems to give return true or false result. I want the nearest point from the list rather than a boolean value.

Comment: what does `distanceToLine(LatLng p, LatLng start, LatLng end)` return? true / false? or double?

Comment: @pskink it seems to return a double value which contains distance only. But I'm not getting on how to implement it.

Comment: Too inefficient to do `distanceToLine` for each segment of the Polyline, and take minimum distance?

Comment: did you check `PolyUtil.java` source code? if so, whats unclear in `distanceToLine` implementation and finding the `LatLng` of the closest point?

Comment: This link will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104809/find-the-closest-point-on-polygon-to-user-location